How to declare the type of the attribute of an undeclared variable
I want to declare the type of a variable which I do not declare myself, but which I know exists.
Motivation
I am currently working with the kivy library, which does a poor job indicating to static type checkers what types its fields have. I would like to indicate the types myself so I can get autocompletions. In the example below, self.ids will be a DictProperty (I believe this is a subclass of a dict) and I want to declare the type of self.ids.task_list_area.
Problem statement
How do I declare the type of self.ids.task_list_area in the following code?
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    task_list = ["Do Homework", "Take out Trash"]

class DetailsScreen(Screen):

    manager: MyScreenManager # this works

    # ids: dict
    # ids.task_list_area: BoxLayout # this does not work because ids does not exist

    def display_tasks(self):
        print(self.manager.task_list) # this is correctly infered as list[str]

        # this works at runtime, but the type checker has no clue what is happening
        print(self.ids.task_list_area) 

    def display_tasks_with_annotation(self):
        self.ids.task_list_area: BoxLayout # this does not error, but does not work either

        print(self.ids.task_list_area) # type checker still knows nothing


display_tasks_annotation isn't being type-checked at all, as it has no argument or return-type annotations. Add one, or use the appropriate type-checker option to force unannotated functions to be type-checked, and you'll get errors.

display_tasks_with_annotation is being type checked, it has infered types of display_tasks_with_annotation(self: DetailsScreen) -> None. the internals of the function are also still type checked by the tools I am using.

You should annotate ids with a type for which it is known that it has an attribute task_list_area of type BoxLayout.
If kivy doesn't provide such a type, you can create one using typing.Protocol:
from typing import Protocol

class HasTaskListArea(Protocol):
    task_list_area: BoxLayout

class DetailsScreen(Screen):
    ids: HasTaskListArea
    # ...


First, in Python, if you want to explicitly specify the type of a variable, you can use type annotations. In the code you give:
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    # Here I try to type annotate self.ids.task_list_area as BoxLayout
    ids.task_list_area: BoxLayout

Such declarations are not standard syntax in Python. In Python, a common way to type annotations on class properties is to use them inside the class's methods, such as the __init__ method. If you want to implement the type annotation to self.ids.task_list_area correctly, you can modify it as follows:
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids.task_list_area: BoxLayout = None

This type annotations the property in the class's initialization method and initializes it to None. Of course, you can also assign an initial reasonable value according to the actual situation.

I tried this, it does not work. It has the same issue that found with my attempt. Namely, that while it does compile, none of the tools can recognized the type has been applied.
